# Error when Posting or patching EducationClass with MSGraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm trying to POST or PATCH an education class using Microsoft Graph but always get and error.

Request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes
```

```json
{
  "description": "Health Level 1",
  "classCode": "Health 501",
  "displayName": "Health 1",
  "externalId": "11019",
  "externalName": "Health Level 1",
  "externalSource": "sis",
  "mailNickname": "fineartschool.net"
}
```

Response

```json
{
  "code": "AccessDenied",
  "message": "Required scp claim values are not provided.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "e1183015-d942-491a-9949-4aa73bbef893",
    "date": "2018-06-21T08:44:35"
  }
}
```

My App has the needed permissions for creating an education class. (for testing, my app has all the application and delegated permissions possible). Posting users, groups etc is no problem.

[image: App Permissions]

More specific the needed permission: [image: Roster permission]

After assigning the permission in the AD portal I did the following:

- Get admin consent for the app `https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant/adminconsent?client_id=myClientID&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURI`
- Get the authorization code `https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myClientID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURI&response_mode=query&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/`
- Get the access token

All with success.
After getting the Access Token I have the following scopes:

- .....
- EduRoster.Read
- EduRoster.ReadBasic
- EduRoster.ReadWrite
- ...

The Graph documentation says you need the permission Application `EduRoster.ReadWrite.All`

Also tested a POST and PATCH in Graph Explorer but get the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API requires "Application" rather than "Delegated" scopes. As you mentioned, it specifically requires the `EduRoster.ReadWrite.All` scope.

Which scopes get applied to a token depends entirely on which OAuth Grant you used to obtain the token:

- Authorization Code Grant = Delegated
- Implicit Grants = Delegated
- Client Credentials Grant = Application

The reason you're not getting this scope in your Access Token is that you're using the Authorization Code grant (`response_type=code`) which will always result in Delegated scopes getting assigned.

In order to make this call, you'll need to obtain a token using the [Client Credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service).

You might also find this article helpful (full disclosure, I am the author): [Application vs Delegated Scopes](https://massivescale.com/application-vs-delegated-scopes/).