# How to resolve error when creating an education class with Microsoft.Graph .NET SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an education class using C# (.NET6) with the Microsoft.Graph nuget package, version 5.15.0.

However, this throws an exception with: ResponseStatusCode = 400; Message = Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.; Error = The expression cannot be evaluated. A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.

I'm authenticating using the client credentials flow with a client secret (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#using-a-client-secret).

See previous related questions:
[Microsoft Graph Education API Method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892605/microsoft-graph-education-api-method-not-allowed) and
[Error when Posting or patching EducationClass with MSGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965435/error-when-posting-or-patching-educationclass-with-msgraph?rq=4)

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID";
var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
    
var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
     AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};
    
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

The registered app has the required permissions (i.e. EduRoster.ReadWrite.All https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/educationclass-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

[Permissions for registered app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IBx6.png)

I'm using the example code provided in the Graph REST API v1.0 documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/educationclass-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples).

```
var requestBody = new EducationClass
{
    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.educationClass",
    DisplayName = "String",
    MailNickname = "String",
    Description = "String",
    CreatedBy = new IdentitySet
    {
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.identitySet",
    },
    ClassCode = "String",
    ExternalName = "String",
    ExternalId = "String",
    ExternalSource = EducationExternalSource.Sis,
    ExternalSourceDetail = "String",
    Grade = "String",
    Term = new EducationTerm
    {
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.educationTerm",
    },
};

var result = await graphClient.Education.Classes.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

This throws an exception with:
ResponseStatusCode = 400,
Message = Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
Error = The expression cannot be evaluated. A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.

With the same app I can successfully:

Get education classes: `var result = await graphClient.Education.Classes.GetAsync();`
Get users: `var result = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();`
Create groups: `var result = await graphClient.Groups.PostAsync(requestBody);`
Create teams: `var result = await graphClient.Teams.PostAsync(requestBody);`

I've tested this in two tenancies with the same result. Unfortunately I'm unable to test it via the Graph Explorer, as it doesn't include the education endpoint.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Failure due to inclusion of externalSource property

Following Oliver's advice, RE Graph Explorer, I got the following in the response: "message": "Payload is invalid. Please remove property 'extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_SyncSource'.". The value of the externalSource property (which I believe is the one identified in the error), should be either "sis" or "manual" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationorganization?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). However, either value results in the above error, but I was able to create the education class when I removed it! Returning to my C# sample code, not populating that property in the EducationClass variable allowed the app to successfully create the education class.

```
var requestBody = new EducationClass
{
    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.educationClass",
    DisplayName = "String",
    MailNickname = "String",
    Description = "String",
    CreatedBy = new IdentitySet
    {
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.identitySet",
    },
    ClassCode = "String",
    ExternalName = "String",
    ExternalId = "String",
    ExternalSourceDetail = "String",
    Grade = "String",
    Term = new EducationTerm
    {
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.educationTerm",
    },
};

var result = await graphClient.Education.Classes.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

That it's now working is obviously great news, many thanks to Oliver, though it also begs the question of whether there may be knock on affects from not populating externalSource property appropriately (I'm updating an existing app using Graph beta that currently populates property with sis). On inspecting the classes I have now created, it seems that the default value for the property is manual. Perhaps I will be able to update that property, now that its been created. I'll investigate that and update my post with my findings.

Comment: You can test it with Graph explorer. Maybe the auto-completion in the URL won't help you, but if you enter the URL manually it should work.

Comment: Instead call `.ToPostRequestInformation()`. From the returned request object extract whole URL and content and paste both into Graph explorer.